# Order by Week Descending based on current week

Tags: t-sql

Is there way to order this query by week # but starting with the current week then descending order ? So if the current week # was 2 it would order by 2,1,52,51 etc...

```
SELECT 
    SalesPerson
  , CAST(SUM(hours) AS DECIMAL(18 , 2))
  , DATEPART(wk , DATEADD(wk , DATEDIFF(wk , 0 , OrderDate) , 0)) AS Wk#
    FROM Orders
    WHERE OrderDate >= DATEADD(month , -12 , GETDATE())
    GROUP BY DATEADD(wk , DATEDIFF(wk , 0 , OrderDate) , 0)
```

Thanks!
E

Comment: This query won't even run. What are you actually trying to achieve? Provide sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

In your example are weeks 2 and 1 from a different year than the 52 etc? You could then ORDER BY YEAR(OrderDate) DESC, DATEPART(week,OrderDate) DESC
But you would have to add YEAR(OrderDate) to your GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just to order by current week first and then other weeks in descending order you can try below order logic. You can add your SELECT and other logic on top of it.

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN 
DATEPART(week,OrderDate)  - DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN 100 ELSE 
DATEPART(week,OrderDate) 
END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with weeks from different years with the same number…

Anyway: Since you group by weeks, you could simply `ORDER BY MIN(OrderDate) DESC`.